# Ansible: lineinfile module with regexp and looping to add line without regexp

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I would like to add some lines in a file using ansible lineinfile module.

I am trying to match certain patterns in file using regexp and i have another task to add a new line to the EOF. Currently, i am doing it with 2 tasks, one to add new line and other for the regexp loop...

Looking for some ways to club both the tasks together..

```yaml
tasks:
    
- name: Add line to the file   
  lineinfile:
     path: "./file1"
     line: "testline"
     create: yes

- name: Add lines using regexp   
  lineinfile:
     path: "./file1"
     regexp: "{{ items.regexp }}"
     line: "{{ items.line }}"   
  loop:
     - { regexp: 'line1'
         line: 'value1'
       }
     - { regexp: 'line2'
         line: 'value2'
       }
```

I want to achieve this 2 in a single task.. I have seen some options like EOF and insertafter, and looking for some recommendations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to [make variables optional](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#making-variables-optional) using the `omit` filter. We can use this for `regexp` parameter, so that it will be omitted if it is not present in `loop`. Then we can supply `line: testline` in the loop to the same task.

Something like this:

```yaml
    - name: Add lines to file
      lineinfile:
        path: "./file1"
        regexp: "{{ item.regexp | default(omit) }}"
        line: "{{ item.line }}"
        create: yes
      loop:
        - line: testline
        - regexp: line1
          line: value1
        - regexp: line2
          line: value2
```